# python compare 2 frames in single video from openCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a test case to be automated where framework is in python and in that we need to verify that progress bar has been incremented from its earlier position.

Lets say we are watching a video on an application and we need to test whether progress bar/scrub bar has really incremented?

Test automation steps:

1. crop image[PNG] of progress bar.
2. capture or read the PNG and check progress bar status.
3. after 15min, again read or capture second PNG and check progress bar status.
4. Now, compare both png and verify progress bar incremented.

Can you please suggest in python while using *openCV, numpy* modules.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use opencv and numpy to  achieve the same.
First read the frames from video using opencv and then at each 15min of the video passed, we can compare the current and the previous frame by using some similarity algorithms like compare_ssim (available in the scipy.measure).
compare_ssim gives a number close to one if the images are similar and close to zero if they are not. you can easily use a thershold of 0.7 for your use case, since you want to check the exact match.

You can start reading your video by using:

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture('path to your video')`

then use a while loop to loop through the cap and you can access the frame by using

`_, frame = cap.read()`

also you have to import ssim from scipy

`from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim`

then when you have two frames which you want to compare use:

`simlarityIndex = ssim(imageCurrentReshape, imageLoadedReshape)`

similarity index denotes how much your images are similar, the greater the values the similar the images.

hope this helps.

Comment: The compare_ssim line changed. from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim